# Проверка строки на соответствие регулярному выражению

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть список строк которые нужно проверить регулярным выражением на валидность.
Строка следующего типа: `Ab1 @any_text.text instagram.com/anylink`
Она состоит из 3-ех частей, между ними может быть сколько угодно пробелов и/или пропусков строк(enter).

1. Первый элемент всегда должен содержать значение `Ab1`.
2. Второй элемент всегда должен начинаться с символа `@` и сразу за ним(без пробела) слово которое может состоять из латинских букв, цифр и символов `_` и `.`
   Пример:`@sample.text` или `@sample2_text`или `@sample3_text.text2`.
3. Третий элемент это ссылка на инстаграм, она может содержать `https://` а может и не содержать, но обязательно надо проверить чтобы присутствовало `instagram.com/` и после этого не пустота.

Я пишу на PHP и мне нужно регулярное выражение которым можно проверить на валидность строку которую я описал выше.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$s = 'Ab1 @any_text.text instagram.com/anylink';
$test = preg_match('/Ab1\s+@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\.?[a-zA-Z_0-9]+\s+(.+)?instagram.com\/./', $s);
```

Comment: Проблема с проверкой ссылки, нужно просто наличие instagram.com/ не, важно что есть до, но важно чтобы было что-то после. Сейчас некоторые валидные ссылки не проходят по этому регулярному выражению

Comment: возможно не проходит http или https://www. Поправил